# Trigger Control-M folder but it should ignore few jobs in the Folder

Tags: scheduler, control-m

I am modifying an existing Control M folder. In that folder, there are 3 jobs in sequence - (Job1 -> Job2 -> Job3). I want to disable 1st and 3rd job so that those do not get triggered(or at least does not execute anything) when Folder is triggered. I do not want to permanently delete the job.

Is there a way to leave a job in Folder and Control M will ignore/bypass that job when Folder is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

On the General tab of the job definition there is a checkbox named "Run as Dummy".
Check this and the jobs will order in and run as normal except that when it comes time for execution they will simply End OK. They will not execute the command/script that would normally be executed.